# Open Admin Menu Item in New Tab

Tags: magento2, admin, menu, tabs, adminmenu

I have a custom module and created **etc/adminhtml/menu.xml**

I want to open my menu item in new browser tab.

Is there any option available in magento to achieve this/set **target="_blank"** ?

Any help would be appreciated !!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. I didn't know it is that easy. I just tried it myself and it is working.

Just use `target="_blank"` in xml like this:

```
<add id="Vendor_Module::id"
             title="Menu title"
             module="Vendor_Module"
             sortOrder="60"
             parent="Vendor_Module::parent"
             action="your_action"
             resource="Vendor_Module::resource"
             target="_blank" />
```

Comment: You are right. It was so easy. I have upvoted your answer :)

Comment: Thanks Mohit :)

Comment: yup, worked ... didnt know about it !!!!

Answer (score 3):

Try this code in any of your JS files which are being called in the backend:

```
require(['jquery'],
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#nav li a").attr("target", "_blank");
    });
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to name the tab instead of using _blank, so multiple clicks on your menu item don't open multiple tabs.